# Product attributes on wishlist

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, wishlist

I'm trying to display a couple of product attributes on the wishlist page.
However, when I call **`$product->getData('attribute_code')`** it returns NULL.

Here is the code I currently have in place:

> app/code/vendor/extension/etc/catalog_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <!-- Wishlist Page -->
    <group name="wishlist_item">
        <attribute name="binding"/>
        <attribute name="used"/>
        <attribute name="format"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

> app/design/frontend/vendor/Theme/Magento_Wishlist/templates/item/list.phtml

```
$test = $product->getData('binding');
var_dump($test);    // displays NULL
```

I looked under
**Store -> Attributes -> Product -> binding -> Storefront Properties**
and **"Used in Product Listing"** is set to **"Yes"**

I also toggled **"Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront"** with no change.

What am I missing?

Comment: might be related to your question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154296/load-additional-product-attributes-in-wishlist?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @magemfs That did it.  Thanks

Comment: that's great! :)